# How to convert a string in java-format ddMMyyyyHmmss to a date by Oracle function to_date ()?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, simpledateformat, to-date

For example, there is a string line `0106201395810` (or `31052013155754`), which fits the format of `new SimpleDateFormat ("ddMMyyyyHmmss")`, ie in the first case, *1 June 2013, 9 hours 58 minutes 10 seconds*. Variant with `to_date ('0106201395810 ',' DDMMYYYYHH24MISS ')` is not suitable because it involves two characters in **HH24**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try reassembling the string along these lines to have a zero in the right place- and use the `DDMMYYYYHH24MISS` format

```
to_date(
 case length(input)
  when 14 THEN -- the length is OK: this has 2 digits at the hour
     input
  when 13 THEN -- length is one short, have to add one '0'
     substr(input,0,8) || '0' || substr(input, 9)
  END,
'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS')
```

Though I must say, this is **ugly**, and probably has "less than optimal" performance... I'd much rather change the Java side format, as this format is clearly not a standard one. Individualism can be good at times - this is clearly not the case. This will just cause pain in the long term...

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure about your specific need to use ddMMyyyyHmmss ; myself will be using HH for a 24hrs date format

Java

```
String s1 = "0106201395810";
Date d1 = (new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHmmss")).parse(s1);
String s2 = (new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")).format(d1);
System.out.println("s2 "+s2);
```

SQL

```
select to_date ('01062013095810', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS' ) from dual
```